# The localhost page isn’t working

Tags: php, iis-7, oci8

I am using IIS 7 with oci8 with php and when I am writing

```
$connection= oci_connect('username', 'password', 'localhost/XE');
```

and its showing me error

> The localhost page isn’t working
>   localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

help me

Comment: 1) Check the error message in your error log under `C:\Windows\Temp\PHP??_errors.log` (`??` is your PHP version and may vary) 2) For development, it's probably best to enable error display instead of the 500 page: http://serverfault.com/questions/19561/how-can-i-display-and-log-php-errors-on-iis7

Comment: php_fcgi_err.log is not showing any error

Comment: But there must be one otherwise you wouldn't see 500. Then please try enabling error display instead, as explained in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: can you run php from the command line with the script and see if it outputs anything on start up ? I think i've had issues when i've not had the oracle instant client libraries installed - and it's not been able to load the php module

Comment: @CherryDt my error handling as follows log_errors = On is it ok?

Comment: Yes so please update it the way I linked, check what happens with `display_errors = On`

Comment: now display_errors = On and i getting error 
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\index.php on line 3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all in IIS rub your simple PHP page

if it run successfully then run this code

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

if you are not able to see oci8 driver in this page then search  **Oracle Instant Client** for php
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

also copy same DLL in system32 and system

then again restart IIS and then see in **phpinfo()** if oci8 driver display then

run this connection code

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36057262/2125924

Comment: then try my code written over this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36057262/2125924

Comment: i am getting **Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()** error while running ur code

Comment: then your phpinfo have problem 
you do not have extension enable

Comment: contact me if you want then I could help you on chintanggor@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks to all problem solved, problem was with my oci driver